# Why are these two SQL date functions not providing the same answer

Tags: t-sql

I've actually already solved the problem, but I'm trying to understand why the problem occurred because as far as I can see it has no reason to happen. 
I have a rather large query that I run to prepare a table with some often used combinations. Generally, it only contains 2 years of data. Occasionally I will reconstruct it. While doing this I tweaked the query to add more information, but suddenly the result no longer matched up to the old query. Comparing the old to the new I noticed several missing orders. Amazingly, even after removing the tweaked parts the results still didn't match up.

I ultimately tracked the problem down to my WHERE clause, which was different from how I did it last time.

The type of the orderdate column I go over has type (datetime, null)

One of the orders that was omitted had this as date:

```
2018-12-23 20:58:52.383
```

An order that was included had this as date:

```
2019-01-28 15:20:49.107
```

It looks exactly the same to me.

The entire query is the same, except for the WHERE clause. My original where was:

```
WHERE DATEPART(yyyy,tbOrder.[OrderDate]) >= DATEPART(yyyy,GETDATE()-2)
```

My new where is now:

```
WHERE tborder.[OrderDate] >= DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE())-2, 0)
```

Any help in understanding why the original where clause drops some lines would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide us with sample data. From there, the results from query 1 and results from query 2...

Comment: Thank you for setting it in code brackets, I couldn't figure it out in the interface. But I've found it now. 
Can you tell me what other sample data you are looking for? 
Would you like more date examples? Or a complete set of columns?

Comment: The first query returns rows in the current year, and can't take advantage of indexes. The other all rows since January 1st two years ago and does take advantage of indexes on `OrderDate`. Both queries look weird. What do you *actually* want? BTW Such queries become a *lot* easier when you use a Calendar table

Comment: You can easily check what each expression returns with a `SELECT` statement: `select DATEPART(yyyy,GETDATE()-2),  DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()) - 2, 0)` The results are completely different in each case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are doing two different things. First predicate,

```
WHERE DATEPART(yyyy,tbOrder.[OrderDate]) >= DATEPART(yyyy,GETDATE()-2)
```

Take all order dates that are bigger than the year for the day before yesterday or two days before. Notice that, `-2` is inside the brackets.

Second predicate,

```
WHERE tborder.[OrderDate] >= DATEADD( yy, DATEDIFF( yy, 0, GETDATE() ) - 2, 0)
```

Take all order dates bigger than two years before, i.e., `datediff(yy,startdate,enddate)` will return the year result of the difference between today and the initial value for `date` datatype, which is `1900-01-01`. Then, add this, `-2`, to `1900-01-01`. The second expression is the form of:

> 1900 + ( 201X - 1898 )

I simplified 1900 - 2 = 1898.

Comment: `DATEPART(yyyy,GETDATE()-2)` returns the current year, not the day before yesterday. The second one returns January 1st two years ago

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes, I meant the year of the day before yesterday. I am going to edit that to be clear.

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe it took me this long to notice a stray bracket, I even had our resident IT man have a look at it and he overlooked it. I feel both relieved and incredibly stupid at the same time. :)

`WHERE DATEPART(yyyy,tbOrder.[OrderDate]) >= DATEPART(yyyy,GETDATE() ) -2`

Normally I do this, which does get the same result. With the bracket before the -2.

Comment: @RoelDyky there's no reason to write such a complicated expression in the first place

Comment: @RoelDyky glad to be helpful, when I saw the `-2` inside the brackets the first thing come to my mind it was that probably that was the error. Because if not the two predicates evaluate equally to true for both cases.

Answer (score 0):

The two expressions return completely different things, so it shouldn't be a surprise the results are different. The first one returns the *current* year as a number (or the year of the day before yesterday to be precise). The second one returns January 1st two years ago.

You can put both expressions in a SELECT query to see what they return :

```
select DATEPART(yyyy,GETDATE()-2),  DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()) - 2, 0)
```

The result is :

```
2019    2017-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

Both expressions are more complex than they need to be. The *first* condition will also harm performance because `DATEPART(yyyy,tbOrder.[OrderDate])` prevents the server from using any indexes that cover `OrderDate`.

The question doesn't explain what you actually want to return. If you wanted to return all rows in the current year you can use :

```
Where 
    OrderDate >=DATEFROMPARTS( YEAR(GETDATE()) ,1,1) and 
    OrderDate < DATEFROMPARTS( YEAR(GETDATE()) + 1,1,1)
```

The same can be used to find rows two years in the past :

```
Where 
    OrderDate >= DATEFROMPARTS( YEAR(GETDATE()) -2 ,1,1) and 
    OrderDate < DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1,1,1)
```

All rows since January 1st two years ago :

```
Where OrderDate >= DATEFROMPARTS( YEAR(GETDATE()) -2 ,1,1)
```

All those queries can take advantage of indexes that cover `OrderDate`.

Date range queries become a *lot* easier if you use a [Calendar table](https://www.sqlshack.com/designing-a-calendar-table/). A Calendar table is a table that contains eg 50 or 100 years' worth of dates with extra columns for month, month day, week number, day of week, quarter, semester, month and day names, holidays, business reprorint periods, formatted short, long dates etc.

This makes yearly, monthly or weekly queries as easy as joining with the Calendar table and filtering based on the month or period you want.

In this case, retrieving rows two yeas in the past would look like :

```
From Orders inner Join Calendar on OrderDate=Calendar.Date
Where Calendar.Year=YEAR(GETDATE())-2
```

That may not looks so impressive but what about Q2 two years ago?

```
From Orders inner Join Calendar on OrderDate=Calendar.Date
Where Calendar.Year=YEAR(GETDATE())-2 and Quarter=2
```

Two years ago, same quarter

```
From Orders inner Join Calendar on OrderDate=Calendar.Date
Where Calendar.Year=YEAR(GETDATE())-2 and Quarter=DATEPART(q,GETDATE())
```

Retrieving totals for the current quarter for the last two years :

```
SELECT Year,Quarter,SUM(Total) QuarterTotal
From Orders inner Join Calendar on OrderDate=Calendar.Date
Where Calendar.Year > YEAR(GETDATE())-2 and Quarter=DATEPART(q,GETDATE())
GROUP BY Calendar.Year
```

Comment: I didn't know about the datepart messing with the indexes, in hindsight it seems logical. Thank you for your excellent explanation and tips.

I have a calender table for use in a different tool, but never thought about using it for inner joins selecting.

The goal was to get 2 complete years of history in the prepared table.